# Knex select always returns pending promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, knex.js

I am writing a simple function to query my database with Knex in Node. Everything I've tried returns `Promise { <pending> }`

Function to query the DB:

```
const queryTable = async () => {
  const data = await knex
    .select("*")
    .from(TABLE_NAME)

  return data;
};
```

I've tried calling the function in it's own async/await wrapper, and I've tried the .then() callback after... No luck. Any leads appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to `console.log(data)` in this function? Do you `await` the function `queryTable` where it's called?

Comment: "*Everything I've tried returns Promise { <pending> }*" - that's normal and expected, and unavoidable.

Comment: "*I've tried calling the function in it's own async/await wrapper, and I've tried the .then() callback after... No luck.*" - please [edit] your question to show us what exactly you did, show us the output you got, and explain how that didn't work for you.

Comment: There is no such thing as `async/await` wrapper. If you ever created such a wrapper you can **only** call the wrapper inside an `async` function and `await` the wrapper therefore the wrapper is not useful at all - it would be the same as using `knex` without using any wrappers.

Answer (score -1):

Try `const data = await knex(TABLE_NAME).select()` - does that work?